# why ng-bind is not working with ng-app

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs now. When I tried ng-bind with ng-app, it's not working.
when I kept it empty like ng-app="", it worked. 
Can anyone explain this?

```
<!doctype html >
<html lang="en" >
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
 </head>
     <body>

        <div ng-app = "">
         <p>Enter your Name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "name"></p>
         <p>Hello <span ng-bind = "name"></span>!</p>
        </div>


     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry its unclear.

Comment: Define "not working" precisely. What do you expect to happen, what happens inbstead, what is the error message, if any, in the console. Post the code that has a problem, not the code which works fine.

Comment: when we type anything in the text box it should come next to "hello", but when  use ng-app="some name" , the value is not getting displayed when i type something in the text box . But same is getting dispalyed when I kept it like ng-app=""..

Comment: And have you defined the module "some name"? Where is your JavaScript code? Have you looked in the browser console for an error? Have you read it?

Comment: Its working for me, Please check this https://plnkr.co/edit/b8wu2bblLTABDeusfVk8?p=preview

Comment: Error in your code is, you might be not defining module. i.e var app = angular.module('someName', []). Hence when your are not giving app name its working. But when you are giving app name it is searching for that module, and the same time it will though an error.

Comment: with ng-app="", the value is getting dispalyed with no error, but with ng-app="somevalue", I can see following error "angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=asdas&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)"

Comment: Looking at few comments above I think, this basic question seems to have exposed "angular skills" of some developers.

Comment: defining angular module solved the issue, thanks USER2. but is it necessary always to define angular module??

thanks all for your help..

Comment: My pleasure. A module in AngularJS is a container of the different parts of an application such as controller, service, filters, directives, factories etc. It supports separation of concern using modules. So if you have to create 
modular application, you should create module. And it is good practice as well.

Answer (score 1):

To use ng-app, you need to first give it a name `<div ng-app = "MyApp">`

And add some script at the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('MyApp', []);
</script>
```

Then viola!

Sample:

```
<!doctype html >
<html lang="en" >
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
 </head>
     <body>

        <div ng-app = "MyApp">
         <p>Enter your Name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "name"></p>
         <p>Hello <span ng-bind = "name"></span>!</p>
        </div>


     </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('MyApp', []);
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot to add i.e. `ng-init="name='John Doe'"`